# Provide a missing network via tunnel to a gateway having access to that network

Tags: routing, tunneling

I'm very new to tunneling, so I may either misunderstand the concepts, or I made some beginner's mistake:
Trying to add new SLES15 hosts to an existing infrastructure I tried to provide a connection to a network that the local host has no access to via a gateway.
See the image for illustration:

[image: Illustrating the scenario]

We have a `bond0` / `br0` network that connects all hosts.
The `bond1` / `br1` network is not available to all hosts, but is available for the hosts tagged **3** and **X** (being a class of similar hosts).

My idea was to configure an IPIP tunnel at hosts **3** and **16** in a way that **16** forwards all `bond1` traffic to **3** via `bond0` while **3** may forward the traffic to **X** using `bond1` (one representative for a set of hosts).
Traffic returned from **X** to **3** via `bond1` should be forwarded via `tun16` through `bond0` to **16**, then.

In a first step I tried the tunnel between **16** and **3** with a setup like this (with more than one node like **16** node **3** will need one tunnel and one route for each such node, right?):

```
16:~ # ip tunnel add tun1 mode ipip remote 172.20.78.3 dev br0
16:~ # ip addr add 172.20.78.16 dev tun1
16:~ # ip link set up tun1
16:~ # ip route add 172.20.78.0/23 via 172.20.78.3 dev tun1 onlink
16:~ # ip route show
default via 172.20.17.254 dev br0
172.20.16.0/23 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.16.16
172.20.78.0/23 via 172.20.78.3 dev tun1 onlink

03:~ # ip tunnel add tun116 mode ipip remote 172.20.16.16 dev bond0
03:~ # ip addr add 10.3.78.16 dev tun116
03:~ # ip link set up tun116
03:~ # ip route add 172.20.78.16 via 172.20.78.16 dev tun116 onlink
03:~ # ip route show
default via 172.20.17.254 dev bond0
10.2.2.0/23 dev bond2 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.2.3
172.20.16.0/23 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.16.3
172.20.78.0/23 dev bond1 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.78.3
172.20.78.16 via 172.20.78.16 dev tun116 onlink
224.0.0.0/4 dev bond0 scope link
03:~ # sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

When pinging **3** from **16** I see this on **3**:

```
3:~ # tcpdump -n -p -i tun116
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun116, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
14:59:29.036354 IP 172.20.78.16 > 172.20.78.3: ICMP echo request, id 21175, seq 13310, length 64
14:59:29.036389 IP 172.20.78.3 > 172.20.78.16: ICMP echo reply, id 21175, seq 13310, length 64
14:59:29.036601 IP 172.20.78.16 > 172.20.78.3: ICMP echo request, id 21175, seq 13310, length 64
14:59:29.036623 IP 172.20.78.3 > 172.20.78.16: ICMP echo reply, id 21175, seq 13310, length 64
14:59:30.060360 IP 172.20.78.16 > 172.20.78.3: ICMP echo request, id 21175, seq 13311, length 64
...
^C
12 packets captured
12 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

When I try to ping **16** from **3**, I get this:

```
h03:~ # ping 172.20.78.16
PING 172.20.78.16 (172.20.78.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.3.78.16 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.3.78.16 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 172.20.78.16 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2023ms

16:~ # tcpdump -n -v -p  icmp
tcpdump: listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:02:47.329812 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 6681, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 132)
    172.20.16.16 > 172.20.16.3: ICMP 172.20.16.16 protocol 4 port 84 unreachable, length 112
        IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37038, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IPIP (4), length 104)
    172.20.16.3 > 172.20.16.16: IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 53094, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.3.78.16 > 172.20.78.16: ICMP echo request, id 12308, seq 1, length 64
15:02:48.331745 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 6700, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 132)
    172.20.16.16 > 172.20.16.3: ICMP 172.20.16.16 protocol 4 port 84 unreachable, length 112
        IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37051, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IPIP (4), length 104)
    172.20.16.3 > 172.20.16.16: IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 53151, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
```

So the packets come across the tunnel, but the responses do not arrive (it seems to me).

What did I forget or what did I wrong?